# Can android Emulate a HID device?

Tags: android, keyboard, hid

I was attempting to design an app that would allow me to have android emulate a hardware device.
I.E.  a generic keyboard, a generic mouse.

I could essentially plug in my android (HTC) to a computer, and program it to use a software keyboard as the computers hardware keyboard.

I don't have any direction on how to accomplish this.

I only wish to connect USB(not bluetooth).  So that the computer needs 0 installation before working.  And most devices will work in Dos Mode.

Answer (score 5):

You can grab the app and have a look at the code: http://code.google.com/p/androhid/

Little jewels like this shine in the middle of a ocean of useless commercial apps.

Comment: This may be a useful answer for someone else, but the question was quite clear about seeking a USB solution and explicitly rejecting Bluetooth.

Comment: the problem with this, is that you need a rooted device.  How can one do this when the user doesn't have root?

Answer (score 3):

"So that the computer needs 0 installation before working"

I have a Sony Ericsson K750i, and it can behave like a HID device trough Bluetooth. Mouse and/or keyboard, anything what you like.  (This is a basic default factory feature of it)
The only install that I had to do is installing the drivers for the bluetooth device on the laptop.
So we can say that no installation was needed, as you install drivers for bluetooth anyway.

There were some default profiles for different applications (media player, windows, image viewer etc)
But one could created custom profiles too, assigning any mouse or keyboard action to any of they physical keys of the phone.

It would be good to see this exact functionality for Android. I was amazed that it doesn't have this by default. It's a shame.

When I search for Android remote control on the Internet, I all can find is about small physical keyboards for android, or the solution is using wifi which needs a damn special software to run on the computer in the same time.